# Change event owner of an event

Tags: facebook, events, owner

We have a small problem here about the ownership of an event. Is it possible to transfer the ownership between two fanpages? There doesn't seem to be an option in the administration panel so maybe there would be fast way of performing this action via the graph api.

Any ideas?! Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to transfer ownership of event to other Page/User.

Comment: Why is that? Is this by design or is it just something that the fb guys unintentionally left out?